# Laravel + varnish port redirect

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, varnish

I have virtual machine with laravel 5 + nginx + varnish on board.

varnish works on port 80, nginx on 8080.

When i go to admin panel:

```
admin.mysite.ru
```

it must redirect to `admin.mysite.ru/user/login/` if user is not log in. It correct. But when this happend, it redirected to `admin.mysite.ru:8080/user/login/`, that's wrong.

Redirect code is simple: `redirect()->guest('/user/login/');`

Thats problem come after i installed varnish, so, i cant understand how to resolve this problem. Could you give some advice or solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your Nginx configuration (inside *http* or *server* block):

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

This should solve the problem.